# Eclipse remote project stored also locally

Tags: eclipse

I am working on a project, on a windows laptop, which is connected via RSE plugin to the linux server (can be run/tested only there).

So I have only a logical SSH link on my laptop, no actual files. Is it possible to somehow have project stored both on local and remote side? (so that both project are in sync)?

The problem is that the linux server is used for labs/experiments by other employees and its files can be removed any day. Now I'm making manual copy to my local machine at the end of each day, and it's really cumbersome.

Of course I don't have to use RSE if there is any other plugin that can satisfy my needs.

Thanks.

Comment: I think you're asking about [version control](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=version+control&t=ffab&ia=web)? Have a read on that and see if that's along the lines of what you're looking for.

Comment: I don't need anything nearly as powerful as version control software, I just want to have my project both on my local machine and remote server without making manual copy after any change. Any plugin with some functionality that will upload my project to a given remote path will do.

Comment: So something like having your project in a Dropbox folder or similar, synced to both machines?